# Display OAuth 2 new token (for test only)

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, access-token

I have this code which seems to work (no errors) but I would like to be able to display the new token somehow (Console. WriteLine etc.)

```
private static bool CertificateValidationCallBack(HttpRequestMessage arg1, X509Certificate2 arg2, X509Chain arg3, SslPolicyErrors arg4)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            private static async Task<Token> GetElibilityToken(HttpClient client)
            {
                
                string baseAddress = @"https://label.xxxx.dot.net/myToken/api/auth/token";

                string grant_type = "password";
                string client_id = "goldline";
                string Username = "xyz";
                string client_secret = "myPassword";

                var form = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"grant_type", grant_type},
                    {"client_id", client_id},
                    {"Username" , Username },
                    {"client_secret", client_secret},
                };
                {

                    HttpResponseMessage tokenResponse = await client.PostAsync(baseAddress, new FormUrlEncodedContent(form));
                    var jsonContent = await tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Token tok = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(jsonContent);
                    return tok;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `Trace.TraceInformation($"GetElibilityToken: the token being returned is {jsonContent}")` if this is part of an application and check the logging.

Or you could recreate this snippet in Linqpad, setting up your own HttpClient and sending that call with the right credentials that you set up in the `form` object. Then Dump() the results.

Comment: thanks. seems this code return 0 , i have no idea why. what i di is used the postman code generator , which on it i get the token smoothly but when I copy paste it to c# console it returns:  {"error":"invalid_client"} , will post new question with that code